# Filename may prevent running in /etc/update-motd.d

Tags: motd

I added a file to `/etc/update-motd.d` and it didn't run.
And I added another and it did run.

`99-wlan0-RWB` doesn't work.
`99-wlan0` does work.

At first I thought maybe it could be the second hyphen, but no, it's the `RWB`! The only thing I can think of is that my non-`root` user is `rwb`.

It has taken me *months* to find this 'feature'!

What's going on?